# Making an Html5 canvas javascript p2p connection without server

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, client, p2p

I'm getting info before making a decision about how to make my application, and I came to this point. No servers involved, just two users with their applications opened, one of them "acting as server", that means, a simple file.txt in Downloads folder where the progress of the user is saved, and the other client connects to also read and modify it. In case the connection or power shuts off so progress of the session is not lost. No need for full security about possible hackers, it'll be dealed with from another way.

I'be been reading things like node.js, but I want it to be client-sided only. I'm also reading https://webrtc.org/. I read messages from 2010 and going talking about this but saying it was not supported by browsers or stuff... Now the page says it's okay, but... Searching about p2p topic, only old answers appear. What's the status nowadays? Maybe there's a better choice?

Comment: Where does the html5 come from, if there is no server?

Comment: @LorenzMeyer hmmm... I want to make a "light" app, it was originally for a "foroactivo" forum. There you can upload your html and javascript CODE, so users can access it from the forum. The other choice that will be maybe the last, would be throught a facebook group (the app is for people from that group), and I could upload the html5 file there so people access it. I suppose I could upload it with the javascript code to easy access... I think I have to try it. It was originally for the forum so did not test further in case I've to make it for facebook. I'm on it, like searching p2p topic.

Answer (score 1):

You're 100% going to need a server at some point.

The HTML, CSS and JavaScript need to be served from somewhere.

You could use WebRTC to create a peer-to-peer data connection between two browsers but you're still going to need a server to handle signaling (how the two users find each other on the network) and possibly a TURN server to handle network traversal.

Lastly saving the game in a directory on one of the clients will be problematic. There's no way to get the browser to save directly into a file. It's possible to get the browser to offer the file for download via a save dialog but it requires the user to choose where to save. Similarly the browser can't just read the file back from the disk; a user will need to upload it.

Comment: Thanks. My idea was something like thiscouldbebetter.neocities.org/texteditor.html so the user can download and upload the file containing the data like "saving" and "loading" the game state. Is it a bad idea?

Also about the server, the point was like I said, forums like "foroactivo" allow to upload html and javascript code, and it could work from there, so people can access it (thought can't use that server for sql and php purposes). Same if I upload to facebook group (no details how). Not possible that way? Should I search for... free servers for php and sql? Then p2p has no sense I think